# JSX not Working in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jsx

Here is my code i am facing issue in my get function where i write my code in forEach loop it gave an error of quotation(Unterminated String Literal).

```
   var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var dataFile = require('./data/friend.json');
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000); 


    app.get("/" , function(req , res ){
               var data = '';
               dataFile.friends.forEach(function(item){
                 data +='
                <div>    
                 <li>
                    <h1>${item.name}</h1>
                    <h2>${item.Class}</h2>
                </li>
                </div>';
               });
    res.send("Welcome");
    });
    app.listen(app.get('port') , function (err){
        console.log("Server is running at "+ app.get('port'));
    });
```

Comment: use `\`\`` and see if it works. `' '` is string literal. `\`\`` is template literal

Comment: it is working and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not have line breaks in JavaScript strings without concatenating or "escaping" them, unless using template literals (using the back-tick).

There are three ways to go about doing this.

Concatenation:

```
           dataFile.friends.forEach(function(item){
             data +='<div>'+    
             '<li>' +
                '<h1>${item.name}</h1>' +
                '<h2>${item.Class}</h2>' +
            '</li>' +
            '</div>';
           });
```

Escaping Line Breaks:

```
           dataFile.friends.forEach(function(item){
             data +='<div>\    
             <li>\
                <h1>${item.name}</h1>\
                <h2>${item.Class}</h2>\
            </li>\
            </div>';
           });
```

Template Literals:

```
           dataFile.friends.forEach(function(item){
             data +=`<div>    
             <li>
                <h1>${item.name}</h1>
                <h2>${item.Class}</h2>
            </li>
            </div>`;
           });
```

Reference: [SyntaxError: unterminated string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal)

** It is also important to note that creating a string of elements **may** not *instantiate* them in to the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) correctly. This will cause JavaScript to be unable to interact with these elements. DigitalOcean has a [tutorial on this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-make-changes-to-the-dom).

**Alternatively,** you can make use of template literals as mentioned above and available in the above reference link, this will *instantiate* elements inside the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction).